# Hard copied .xlsx file is manyfold larger compared to source file

Tags: excel, vba, file, save, filesize

I have a .xlsb file where I create a hard copied version of a sheet for history purpose.

The .xlsb file (containing multiple sheets with formula and data) is roughly 5mb.

The hard copied version with plain numbers (no formatting) is roughly 117kb.
When I copy the formats as well the file gets 92.5mb and the code runs for almost 2 mins to be fully executed.

I use the following code:

```
Sub save_db()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim db As Worksheet
Dim db_file As Workbook

Set db = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Datenbank")

Set db_file = Workbooks.Add

db.UsedRange.Copy
db_file.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
db_file.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlFormats

db_name = "DB_" & CStr(Date) & ".xlsx"

db_file.SaveAs ("User\DB_Achieve\" & db_name)
db_file.Close


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: So what seems to be the problem? Formatting uses Space, so that is to be expected, .xlsx also tend to use more space compared to .xlsb (which is by design).

Comment: Thats true, but this it is not an argument that the file increases in size 790 times, just because there are colour fillings and date formats applied. Also an .xlsb saves in best case around 50% of space considering same amount of data. The hard copied file has less data but is also almost 20 times bigger. (5mb vs 92.5mb)

Comment: It can be, depending on the formatting and the way (XML) excel saves the data. My guess is that the new excel file saves the formatting for each cell separately. More on this: http://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000398.shtml  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats

Comment: You could unzip your Excel File and check what exactly takes up the space.

Comment: Also, how big is `UsedRange`, are empty Cells also/formatted/filled even thought they are empty, all this would increase the size of the new file.